# Viable strategies for handling non-normalized vertex position values in Wavefront obj files

Tags: opengl, rendering, wavefront

I've noticed that most of the .obj files I try to feed to my rendering engine have position values outside of [-1; 1] range. 
The question is, *how would one preprocess such a mesh so it could fit nicely alongside already loaded, normalized and placed-on-the-scene meshes?*

Consider a situation where I load a normalized mesh to my scene compositing tool. It fits in the OpenGL space so I can see it on the screen. Then I scale, rotate and translate it to where I want it to be placed, saving transformation matrix alongside. Then the next mesh processed the same way, and then the next one, etc. What should I do with a non-normalized mesh? Do i simply calculate it's bounding box and then traverse all the vertices again and scale it down so I could actually see and manipulate it the usual way? Or maybe experienced people can advise other approaches? Thanks :)

Comment: You'd just need to get the minimum and maximum positions and scale accordingly.

Comment: Yeaa, thought so, but was still very unsure if this is a correct way to approach the problem.

Comment: What other solution would there be? However be sure to scale it relative to all axes.

Comment: Now i feel kinda awkward for posting such a question

Comment: See [`GetExtents()` & `CenterAndScale()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14887071/44729).