# Drawing VBOs in OpenGL not working

Tags: c++, opengl, wavefront

I'm writing a simple class that parses an OBJ and renders the obj after that. I've already written a method for drawing vertex arrays from RAM and I wanted to optimize it a bit (I read that using VBOs gets you x4 times the framerate!).

Sadly I'm failing spectacularly, I've followed a bunch of tutorials to no avail. 
Here's the parser and the calls to store the vertices and indices buffers on GPU, I've througly debugged the parser itself and it's ok. Both vertexBuffer and vertexIndices are loaded up fine (I've printed them and manually checked them against the obj file).

```
Mesh::Mesh(string path) {
float* normals;
float* faces;
float* textures;
string fullpath = path + ".obj";
this->mats = loadMtl(path); //Loads a Material list, not used now drawing white
string line;
ifstream objFile(fullpath.c_str());
if (objFile.is_open()) {
    objFile.seekg(0, ios::end);
    long fileSize = long(objFile.tellg());
    objFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    // Init buffers and indices
    unsigned int inserted = 0;

    string currentMtl = "";

    float* vertexBuffer = new float[fileSize];
    float* textureBuffer = new float[fileSize];
    float* normalBuffer = new float[fileSize];

    unsigned int* vertexIndices = new unsigned int[fileSize];
    unsigned int* normalIndices = new unsigned int[fileSize];
    unsigned int* textureIndices = new unsigned int[fileSize];

    int connectedVert = 0;
    int textureCoords = 0;
    int normalsCount = 0;

    int vertexIndex = 0;

    string prefix = "usemtl";

    while (!objFile.eof()) {
        getline(objFile, line);
        if (line.c_str()[0] == 'v' && line.c_str()[1] == ' ') {
            line[0] = ' ';
            sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "%f %f %f ",
                &vertexBuffer[connectedVert],
                &vertexBuffer[connectedVert + 1],
                &vertexBuffer[connectedVert + 2]);
            connectedVert += 3;
        }
        else if (line.c_str()[0] == 'v' && line.c_str()[1] == 't') {
            line[0] = ' ';
            line[1] = ' ';
            sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "%f %f ",
                &textureBuffer[textureCoords],
                &textureBuffer[textureCoords + 1]);
            textureCoords += 2;
        }
        else if (line.c_str()[0] == 'v' && line.c_str()[1] == 'n') {
            line[0] = ' ';
            line[1] = ' ';
            sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "%f %f %f ",
                &normalBuffer[normalsCount],
                &normalBuffer[normalsCount + 1],
                &normalBuffer[normalsCount + 2]);
            normalsCount += 3;
        }
        else if (line.c_str()[0] == 'f') {
            line[0] = ' ';

            if (textureCoords > 0) {
                sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "%i/%i/%i %i/%i/%i %i/%i/%i",
                    &vertexIndices[vertexIndex], &textureIndices[vertexIndex], &normalIndices[vertexIndex],
                    &vertexIndices[vertexIndex + 1], &textureIndices[vertexIndex +1], &normalIndices[vertexIndex +1],
                    &vertexIndices[vertexIndex + 2], &textureIndices[vertexIndex +2], &normalIndices[vertexIndex +2]);
            }
            else {
                sscanf_s(line.c_str(), "%i//%i %i//%i %i//%i",
                    &vertexIndices[vertexIndex], &normalIndices[vertexIndex],
                    &vertexIndices[vertexIndex+1], &normalIndices[vertexIndex +1],
                    &vertexIndices[vertexIndex+2], &normalIndices[vertexIndex +2]);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                vertexIndices[vertexIndex+j] -= 1;
                normalIndices[vertexIndex +j] -= 1;
                textureIndices[vertexIndex +j] -= 1;
            }
            vertexIndex += 3;
        }
        else if (!strncmp(line.c_str(), prefix.c_str(), strlen(prefix.c_str()))) {
            inserted++;
            // No more vertices, normals or texture coords to load, gen arrays on GPU
            if (currentMtl == "") {
                //Copy vertices to GPU
                glGenBuffers(1, &this->verticesID);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->verticesID);
                glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * connectedVert, vertexBuffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
                /*
                //Won't be bothered with normals or textures right now...
                //Copy normals to GPU
                glGenBuffers(1, &this->normalsID);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->normalsID);
                glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * normalsCount, &normalBuffer[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

                //Copy UV to GPU
                if (textureCoords > 0) {
                    glGenBuffers(1, &this->textID);
                    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->textID);
                    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * textureCoords, &textureBuffer[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
                }*/
            }
            else {
                // Filled up an index array, copy it.
                this->indices.push_back(0);
                this->faces.push_back(vertexIndex);
                glGenBuffers(1, &this->indices[this->indices.size() - 1]);
                glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->indices[this->indices.size() - 1]);
                glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * vertexIndex, vertexIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            }
            currentMtl = line.substr(7, line.length());
            vertexIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    // Copy the last indices buffer.
    if (currentMtl != "" && indices.size() < inserted) {
        this->indices.push_back(0);
        this->faces.push_back(vertexIndex);
        glGenBuffers(1, &this->indices[this->indices.size() - 1]);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->indices[this->indices.size() - 1]);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(unsigned int) * vertexIndex, vertexIndices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }

    objFile.close();
    delete[] vertexBuffer;
    delete[] textureBuffer;
    delete[] normalBuffer;

    delete[] vertexIndices;
    delete[] normalIndices;
    delete[] textureIndices;
}
else {
    throw runtime_error("Unable to load obj file: " + path + ".obj");
}
}
```

Finally, here's the draw call. I'm guessing the problem is here but I can't quite put my finger on the issue. I've used glIntercept to see if there's something messed up but I got no errors there.

```
void Mesh::draw() {
    //Binding Vertex array
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->verticesID);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, (void*)0);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < this->indices.size(); i++) {
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // Draw it in plain ol' white
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, this->indices[i]);
        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,this->faces[i], GL_UNSIGNED_INT,(void*)0);
    }
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

In case it's needed, here's the Mesh class declaration:

```
class Mesh {
    public:
        GLuint verticesID, textID, normalsID;
        vector<GLuint> indices;
        vector<GLuint> faces;
        vector<Material> mats;
    public:
       Mesh(string path);
       void draw();
        ~Mesh();
};
```

Setting up OpenGL major version as 2, and minor as 1. As I'm mentioned before, I think OpenGL is set up correctly because I'm able to draw triangles in both direct mode and using vertex pointers from RAM. Any help welcomed :)

Comment: Edit in a [mcve].  Feel free to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14887071/44729) as a base.

Comment: @Rabbid76 the context is the first thing that's set (using SDL). Otherwise I wouldn't be able to use draw arrays.

Comment: @genpfault I'm trying to avoid glVertexPointer calls since it's less efficient. Would you like me to separate the vertex, indices loading to another function?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I'm off to class now but I'll edit the code so that's self contained. Here's the source for now, if you have time to read it: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxpdwU_OmJtnYlRHS3l5aVZpTUE

Comment: Well, stackoverflow won't let me edit the comment. Here's the source for now, if you have time to read it: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxpdwU_OmJtnYlRHS3l5aVZpTUE It's just a camera class, a world class that wraps every vbo in the scene, a mesh class and a material class that's not used right now. EXPERIMENTAL_MESH is the code for the VBO. I'll fix the post when I'm back though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It the constructor of the calss `Mesh` the file is read and the object buffers are generated (`glGenBuffers`). In the destructor `Mesh::~Mesh` the object buffers are destroyed (`glDeleteBuffers`).

But you `push_back` the `Mesh` to a `std::vector`. This means that a temporary `Mesh` object is generated, which reads the file and generate the object buffer in its constructor. At this point all the data are valid and the object buffers are generated (GPU). When calling `std::vector::push_back`, then a new `Mesh` objectis is generated, in the `std::vector`. The object is constructed by the default copy constructor and gets a copy of all the members of the first `Mesh` object. Immediately after this is done, the temporary `Mesh` object gets destroyed and the object buffers get deleted (`glDeleteBuffers`) by the destructor `Mesh::~Mesh` of the temporary object. At this point all the data are gone.

See [**`std::vector::push_back`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/). Put a breakpoint in the destrutor `Mesh::~Mesh`, then you can simply track the expiration.

You should not do the generation and the deletion of GPU objects in the constructor and destructor of a class except you make the class **not** copyable and **not** copy constructable:

```
class Mesh
{
    Mesh(const Mesh &) = delete;
    Mesh & operator = (const Mesh &) = delete;

    ....
};
```

You can quickly fix this behavior for debug reasons, by replacing

```
test.meshes.push_back(Mesh("tri"));
```

by

```
test.meshes.emplace_back("tri");
```

(see [`std::vector::emplace_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/emplace_back/))

But at the end you should do something like:

```
vector<std::unique_ptr<Mesh>> meshes;

meshes.emplace_back(new Mesh("tri"));
```

Comment: I knew my Heap-fobia would screw me some day. You've saved me countless ours. Thank you a lot, it's running fine now.